# Amazon Alexa: slot types

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

Can any one tell me the slot type of the intent which can have long sentences in the English(India) Language? In English(US) I use `AMAZON.StreetAddress` for this purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a custom slot type. According to Amazon, [use of the `Amazon.LITERAL` type is discouraged](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx3IHSFQSUF3RQP/why-a-custom-slot-is-the-literal-solution), and a custom slot type is recommended instead. Usually for custom slot types, you [specify a set of sample values](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/custom-interaction-model-reference.html#custom-slot-syntax). However, based on your use case, it sounds like you want a match that is as close as possible to just catching all possible inputs, which is [Scenario #3 from this Amazon Alexa blog article](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/Tx3IHSFQSUF3RQP/why-a-custom-slot-is-the-literal-solution). As the article's content for the "Catch All" scenario mentions:

> If you use the same training data that you would have used for
>   LITERAL, you’ll get the same results.

IMO, of special importance is the last paragraph regarding Scenario #3.

> If you’re still not getting the results, trying setting the CatchAll
>   values to around twenty 2 to 8 word random phrases (from a random word
>   generator – be really random). When the user says something that
>   matches your other utterances, those intents will still be sent. When
>   it doesn’t match any of those, it will fall to the CatchAll slot. If
>   you go this route, you’re going to lose accuracy because you’re not
>   taking full advantage of Alexa’s NLP so you’ll need to test heavily.

Hope that helps.